# Who create this rectangle in VIsual Studio Code markdown text edit?

Tags: visual-studio-code, markdown

[image: ploblem picture]

Please look up this picture. I opened Visual Studio Code 1.31.0, create new file,
write below, then, the rectangle shown in this picture was appeared.

````
```a`a```
````

I opened Developper tool and checked DOM. I edit `<div style="top:0px;height:19px;" class="view-line">`(`top:0px` => `top:10px`), then, the rectangle doesn't moved.

[image: style top edit]

So, I checked around this element. However, threre is anything like creating the rectangle.

In my Visual Studio Code, too many extension is installed, see [here](https://pastebin.com/S1yZ2Cqj)

Markdown related extension list is below:

```
$code --list-extensions | grep markdown
bierner.markdown-emoji
bierner.markdown-mermaid
DavidAnson.vscode-markdownlint
geeklearningio.graphviz-markdown-preview
shd101wyy.markdown-preview-enhanced
TomasHubelbauer.vscode-markdown-table-format
yzhang.markdown-all-in-one
```

So, I download Visual Studio Code Insider 1.32.0, install extensions shown below one by one, the rectangle was not drawn.

Who cretate the rectangle? Or, how to investigate?

As far as I know, markdown-it recognize the markdown as single code tag so that non markdown-it related process draw the rectangle, I think.

Environment

- Windows 10 Home 1809
- Visual Studio Code 1.31.0

Comment: It looks like VoiceOver in iOS (a screen reader) highlighting its focused element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a feature introduced in [v1.5.0](https://github.com/yzhang-gh/vscode-markdown/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#150-20180624) of Markdown All in One. You can control it with setting `markdown.extension.syntax.decorations`.

Comment: Thank you. I created issue about parser on correct place!
https://github.com/yzhang-gh/vscode-markdown/issues/390